Movie about global warming, begins with three guys working on a huge iceberg and one of them makes it break
I remember two guys entering a little cabin after work while the third one has another thing left to do outside. He fails and the whole iceberg starts crackin. After it tears apart he jumps the hole and saves their research documents, or something like that.

This is the 2004 film, The Day After Tomorrow..

The film opens with three Glaciologists mining for core samples in the arctic shelf. They don't actually appear to cause the ice shelf to 'break', the film implies its simply a co-incidence that they are there (and the break occurs straight through their camp, as they are mining).

